# Passing MP3 from controller to view .NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass a FileContentResult from my controller that has a byte[] MP3 file into the view,
my problem is when I do that(return a file to view) the view renders a new HTML page with an audio player.

I want to have a player on my Html page waiting for an audio file from the controller, maybe as a model? not sure.
any help is appreciated!

```
   [Route("morse")]
    public FileResult Morse(string msg)
    {       
        _decoder.MorseBuilder(msg, out byte[] audio, out TimeSpan time);
        return File(audio, "audio/mpeg");   //byte[]
    }
```

currently my view (Index.cshtml) is empty.

this is what I ended up doing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Url.Action()` method to call the action method and load MP3 file, please refer to the following sample code:

```
public class AppFile
{
    [Key]
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult FileIndex()
    {             
        return View(_context.AppFiles.ToList());
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetVnAudioStream(int id)
    {
        if (id > 0)
        {
            var pronunciation = _context.AppFiles.Where(c=>c.FileID == id).FirstOrDefault().Content;
            if (pronunciation != null && pronunciation.Length > 0)
            {
                return File(pronunciation, "audio/mp3");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

View Page:

```
@model IEnumerable<netcore5.Models.AppFile>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FileID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FileName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContentType)
            </th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <audio controls>
                        <source src='@Url.Action("GetVnAudioStream","Home", new {id = item.FileID})' type='audio/mp3' />
                    </audio>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContentType)
                </td> 
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this example, its a good way of doing it but not what I intended to do, I think explained myself poorly of what I am trying to achieve.

the way i'm calling the action is by going to localhost:port/morse?msg=text
then the action method is called and it takes the query param, does its work and returns a MP3 file back to the view. (the problem was that on return the browser was rendering a new HTML page with a player with the MP3 result in it).

what I ended up doing is storing the file in the model, calling the action method from an AJAX call.

Comment: then storing the models property ("...---..." the decoded morse from text to morse)  in a hidden html tag calling another AJAX call to another action method that would turn the morse into sound and on success populate a MP3 player with the bytes.